# Issues with sklearn on Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda, scikits

I am trying to use sklearn.
Scikit-learn and posthocs has already been installed, but when I import it indicated module was not installed.

I followed the advice of another post, and uninstalled and re-installed scikit and it now is showing in my modules list as normal, but now when I go to import:

`import scikit_posthoc` and `scikit_learn`

conda list returns:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\GregorashS\.conda\envs\statsenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bottleneck                1.3.4            py39hcdd71bb_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h33f27b4_0
ca-certificates           2018.4.16                     0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.11.17         pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.10.4               h5b497f6_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h9f7ea03_3556
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9e                   hc431981_0
kiwisolver                1.4.2            py39h6986bd8_0
lazy-loader               0.2                      pypi_0    pypi
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2450fd4_1
libwebp                   1.2.2                hc431981_0
littleutils               0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
lz4-c                     1.9.3                hc431981_1
matplotlib                3.5.1            py39h9f7ea03_1
matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py39h6986bd8_1
mkl                       2021.4.0           h9f7ea03_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39hc431981_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h116a794_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hcf78d83_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
numexpr                   2.8.1            py39hdbe7276_2
numpy                     1.21.5           py39hf27c404_3
numpy-base                1.21.5           py39hb79ded8_3
openssl                   1.1.1o               hc431981_0
outdated                  0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.2            py39h6986bd8_0
pandas-flavor             0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
patsy                     0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    9.0.1            py39hc6e4d3e_0
pingouin                  0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.2.4           py39h9f7ea03_0
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py39h6986bd8_6
python                    3.9.12               h53c7b84_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
requests                  2.28.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py39hcf78d83_1
scikit-posthocs           0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.7.3            py39h300b434_0
seaborn                   0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
setuptools                61.2.0           py39h9f7ea03_0
sip                       4.19.13          py39h6986bd8_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sqlite                    3.38.3               hc431981_0
statsmodels               0.13.2           py39hc431981_0
tabulate                  0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0            py39h9f7ea03_1
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
tk                        8.6.12               hc431981_0
tornado                   6.1              py39hc431981_0
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0
urllib3                   1.26.15                  pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py39h9f7ea03_2
xarray                    2023.4.2                 pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                h559d222_1
zlib                      1.2.12               h3c9058a_2
zstd                      1.5.2                h8c83ad5_0'
```

it returns:
`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: Access is denied.`

I don't know what I need to do, I restarted anaconda and it still says the modules are already installed. Once I run python it all goes out the window.

I followed the advice of another post, and uninstalled and re-installed scikit. This only caused more issues.

Comment: We need more info/  Are you installing in the base conda environment or a new conda environment? Did you install using PIP or Conda?  Can you provide the output of `conda list`?  Are you sure you are activating the environment correctly?

Comment: The environment is already activated- pretty basic 'activate statsenv' that I've already created. I just added it to the base and then activated stats env again and conda list returns added above

Comment: It looks like a bad install or a corrupt package. You can try to install a different version: `conda install scikit-learn==1.2.2`

Comment: Please note how the "Channel" column of the `conda list` output shows a mixture of `conda-forge`, `pypi`, and blank (i.e., `defaults`) entries. Mixing channels like this is the most common cause of DLL importing errors (see [*"Using Multiple Channels"*](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels)). Start over with a new environment and use only one channel.